# Algebraic Manipulation question - trying to get alternate form

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions

I'm currently working on algebraic manipulation, changing algebraic fractions into a chosen alternate form but I've hit a brick wall.

I'm trying to get: 
$$\frac{2(3^x - 2^x)}{3^{x+1} - 2^{x+1}}$$

to the alternate form:

$$\frac{2}{\frac{1}{(3/2)^x-1}+3}$$

Any help will be seriously appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Well, to start with, you should be able to see that $$\frac{2(3^x-2^x)}{3^{1+x}-2^{1+x}}=\cfrac2{\frac{3^{1+x}-2^{1+x}}{3^x-2^x}},$$ so the only thing left to do is show that $$\frac{3^{1+x}-2^{1+x}}{3^x-2^x}=\cfrac1{\left(\frac32\right)^x-1}+3.$$

The key here is to use your exponent rules.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with $$\frac{2(3^x-2^x)}{3^{1+x}-2^{1+x}},$$
divide top and bottom by the parenthesisized part of the top, and split off $3$ and $2$ from the $x+1$ powers, and also rewrite $-2\cdot2^x=-3\cdot 3^3+2^x:$
$$\frac{2}{\frac{3\cdot 3^x-3\cdot 2^x+2^x}{3^x-2^x}}.$$
The denominator is now 
$$3+\frac{2^x}{3^x-2^x}=3+\frac{1}{(3/2)^x-1}.$$

Comment: cheers buddy! I feel as if I'm missing a trick here, but where did 3*2^x come from? I just assumed:
3^(1+x)-2^(1+x) = 3(3^x) - 2(2^x)

Comment: The term $3(3^x)-2(2^x)$ was rewritten as $3(3^x)-3(2^x)+2^x$ so that the first two terms would be 3 times the denominator of the thing under the 2 ... that's where the 3 comes from in the denominator. What's left is the $2^x/(3^x-2^x)$, and the last step is to divide top and bottom of this term by $2^x.$

Comment: @therunningman In my last response I forgot to tag you, so you may not have noticed it. Let me know if the explanation is clear now.